# HTML Checkbox and Single Input in Form

Tags: php, html, checkbox, twig

I'm using [OctoberCMS](http://octobercms.com/) based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

I used [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to generate a simple Gallery using a loop.

You can delete a Single image, or choose with a Checkbox, and click any Delete Button to submit.

`{{ record.name }}` is the image name in the database.

#### Form with Twig

[image: gallery]

```
<form method="POST" action="/">

    <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onDelete" >

    <!-- Gallery -->
    {% for record in records %}

        <!-- Image -->
        <img src="images/{{ record.name }}.jpg">

        <!-- Single Image Name -->
        <input type="hidden" name="single" value="{{ record.name }}" />
        <!-- Checkbox Image Name -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="{{ record.name }}">
        <!-- Delete -->
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="delete">Delete</button>

    {% endfor %}

</form>
```

#### PHP

```
function onDelete() {

    $path = '/var/www/mysite/images/';
    $single = $_POST['single'];
    $checkboxes = '';
    $checkboxes = isset($_POST['queued']) ? $_POST['queued'] : array();

    # Checkbox Delete
    if(isset($_POST['queued'])) {
        # Delete each in queued array
        foreach($checkboxes as $name) { 
            File::delete("$path$name.jpg");
        }
    }

    # Single Delete
    else {
        File::delete("$path$single.jpg");
    }

}
```

#### Problem

Rendered HTML

```
<form>
    <img src="images/image1.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="single" value="image1" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="image1" />

    <img src="images/image2.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="single" value="image2" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="image2" />

    <img src="images/image3.jpg">
    <input type="hidden" name="single" value="image3" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="queued[]" value="image3" />
</form>
```

The Checkbox Delete runs the for loop and works.

But Single Delete always deletes the last `name="single"` on the form, `image3`.

I tried setting `$_POST['single']` to an array `name="single[]"` but it deleted *all* files, because they are not `type="checkbox"` and are always `isset` and added to the array.

How can I solve this and have Checkbox Delete and Single Delete in the same form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You UX is not very intuitive to me. Adding a button named "delete checked images" would be better. 
Any way, you could set the dynamic values of your submit

```
{% for record in records %}
    <!-- [...] -->
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="{{ record.name }}">Delete</button>
{% endfor %}
```

Then

```
function onDelete() {

    $checkboxes = isset($_POST['queued']) ? $_POST['queued'] : array();

    // Checkbox Delete
    if(isset($_POST['queued'])) {
        // Delete each in queued array
        foreach($checkboxes as $name) { 
            File::delete("$path$name.jpg");
        }
    }

    // Single Delete
    else {

        $nameFile = $_POST['submit']; // <-----

        File::delete("$path$nameFile.jpg");
    }

}
```

Comment: Won't work as you mixed up attribute type with name. Also, you don't need to make the name dynamic as the value of the clicked button will be set to the post value

Comment: Thanks for helping me solve this, I spent many hours and solutions. It now deletes by checkboxes and single buttons. I've also added a Delete  Checked button.

Comment: @DarkBee It's working, I've tested it several times. Though you say type="submit_{{ record.name }}" should just be type="submit"?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm saying. There aint no type like `submit_blabla`, only valid types are found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Comment: Yes sorry and thanks @DarkBee, I wrote this in a hurry